# How to use Guice Module to instantiate one of multiple fields in a class?

Tags: java, constructor, dependency-injection, guice

I have a class, and create an instance using a regular constructor:

```
class Foo {
  String fooName;
  Bar barObject;
  ExternalService externalService;

  Foo(String fooName, Bar barObject, Service someService){
    this.fooName = fooName;
    this.barObject = barObject;
    this.externalService = externalService;
    //call to super
    }
}


class MyApplication {
  //instantiate ExternalService 
  ...

  Foo foo = new Foo(String fooName, Bar barObject, ExternalService externalService);
}
```

ExternalService is owned by somebody else and they have now provided a Guice Module (something like ExternalServiceModule). How can I make use of this module
to instantiate ExternalService in my Foo class?

I am trying something like

```
class Foo {
  String fooName;
  Bar barObject;
  ExternalService externalService;

  @Inject
  Foo(String fooName, Bar barObject, Service someService){
    this.fooName = fooName;
    this.barObject = barObject;
    this.externalService = externalService;
    //call to super
  }
}
```

and

```
class MyApplication {
    ...
  ExternalServiceModule ecm = new ExternalServiceModule();
  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(ecm);
  Foo foo = injector.getInstance(Foo.class);
}
```

But obviously I am not passing the fooName, and barObject in the second way. How to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are just trying to get an instance of `ExternalService` to pass to your Foo class constructor. You can call `injector.getInstance(ExternalService.class)`:

```
class MyApplication {
  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ExternalServiceModule());
  ExternalService externalService = injector.getInstance(ExternalService.class);
  Bar someBar = new Bar();
  Foo foo = new Foo('someName', someBar, externalService);
}
```

---

But since you are using Guice you probably are looking for [`assisted inject`](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject):

**Foo**

```
public class Foo {
  private String fooName;
  private Bar barObject;
  private ExternalService externalService;

  @Inject
  public Foo(
      @Assisted String fooName,
      @Assisted Bar barObject,
      ExternalService externalService) {
    this.fooName = fooName;
    this.barObject = barObject;
    this.externalService = externalService;
  }

  public interface FooFactory {
    Foo create(String fooName, Bar barObject);
  }
}
```

---

**MyModule**

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(FooFactory.class));
  }
}
```

---

**MyApplication**

```
public class MyApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
        new ExternalServiceModule(), new MyModule());
    FooFactory fooFactory = injector.getInstance(FooFactory.class);

    Bar someBar = new Bar();
    Foo foo = fooFactory.create("SomeName", someBar);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DTing, definitely gives me a direction. But looks like there is something else that I am missing.  Gives me errors like "No implementation for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.ExternalService annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) was bound.
  while locating xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.ExternalService annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=)
    for parameter 4 at com.cerne"

Comment: Not sure what you tried so can't really be of much help. Maybe update your question or post another.

Comment: The first approach worked perfectly for me, and its absolutely simple making me feel sheepish not knowing that. Thanks @DTing. The error turned out to be a an unrelated thing: a configuration item which was expected by the module was not being passed, so I had to add another dependent module in Guice.createInjector .